# Cyclic requests via ajax in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've got a little functionality in my Symfony2 project which just asks for amount of notices waiting for a user in db. It runs every 5 seconds and targets regular Symfony2 controller and action, which checks db. I think it's a overkill to run full framework just for that, but I don't want to add any custom scripts, would love to stick to proper Symfony usage, but without dispatching everything just to get a one number from db. Any guesses?

Comment: Maybe you could create a command http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/console/introduction.html

Comment: and how should I run it from the browser? :O

Comment: If you have to run it every 5 minutes, you can create a cron.

Comment: It's a browser and ajax script that is asking for notices :)